# Including ffmpeg in qt project on windows causes the program to unexpectedly finish

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, dll, ffmpeg

I am trying to include ffmpeg in my qt project on windows. I am running QT4 and compiling with microsoft visual compiler 2010 on 32 bit windows 7. I am trying to include ffmpeg 2.8 which I got the [dev](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/dev/ffmpeg-2.8-win32-dev.7z) and [shared](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/shared/ffmpeg-2.8-win32-shared.7z) downloads from [zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). When I run it I get the following output:

```
Starting (executable path)...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
(executable path) exited with code -1073741819
```

I am able to produce this output with the following:

ffmpeg_test.pro:

```
QT += core
TARGET = ffmpeg_test

INCLUDEPATH += (ffmpeg dev path)/include
LIBS += -L(ffmpeg dev path)/lib
LIBS += -lavformat

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
extern "C"
{
#ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  av_register_all();
  return 0;
}
```

I have put the .dll files from the ffmpeg share bin into the same folder that QT builds ffmpeg_test.exe into. I have also confirmed that they are found using dependency walker which shows a question mark when they are not in that directory and the avformat-56.dll file path when they are (the fact that the .dll files are found does not effect the output of the program).

Dependency walker does reveal that something weird is going on as there are no expected functions, but the functions found in avformat-56.dll look correct. I also have ran Dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS on avformat.lib and it also looks fine (I can post output if it would be helpful). It is worth noting that I have included this version of ffmpeg in a different application on this machine, it was not a qt project however. That project generated its make file with CMake rather than QMake and was built with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 rather than QT Creator.

I have also included other .lib/.dll pairs in qt and they have no problems. I am noticing two differences from those pairs. First in the ffmpeg-dev lib folder instead of having only .lib files (as is the case for all my other .lib/.dll pairs) I also have a .def and a .dll.a file for each library. Second ffmpeg is a c library whereas all my other included libraries are c++.

**update 3/29**:

I have tried replacing the LIBS lines in my .pro with both of the following:

`LIBS += (ffmpeg dev path)/lib/avformat.lib`

`LIBS += (ffmpeg dev path)/lib/libavformat.dll.a`

Both give the same error message. I have also tried adding the following to my .pro file also with no effect.

`DEFINES += __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS`
`QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS += -D_STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS`

Additionally I tried adding `#define inline __inline` to main.cpp as suggested on the ffmpeg [website](http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Linking-to-FFmpeg-with-Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b). Any ideas of things to try would be hugely appreciated!

**update 3/31**:

I have tried to start over with a new Windows build environment but the result remains unchanged with the test code above. (The new environment was able to run a hello world program).

My process for setting up this environment was to install a fresh version of 32 bit windows 7. Install Visual C++ 2010 Express from the [Visual Studio 2010 Express All-in-one ISO](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/5/1E5F1C0A-0D5B-426A-A603-1798B951DDAE/VS2010Express1.iso). Install [Qt 4.8.6 for 32 bit windows and Visual Studio 2010](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.6/qt-opensource-windows-x86-vs2010-4.8.6.exe). And finally install [Qt Creator 2.5.2](http://download.qt.io/archive/qtcreator/2.5/qt-creator-win-opensource-2.5.2.exe). To set up Qt creator I went under tools->options and told it where to find the Qt 4.8.6 qmake. I downloaded the [dev](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/dev/ffmpeg-2.8-win32-dev.7z) and [shared](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/shared/ffmpeg-2.8-win32-shared.7z) builds for ffmpeg 2.8 from Zeranoe. I was missing [stdint.h and inttypes](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/msinttypes/msinttypes-r26.zip) so I downloaded them and put the files in /include/libavutil. Then I corrected any of the header files that complained from  to "stdint.h" ect. I then put the dll files from ffmpeg-2.8-win32-shared/bin into the folder where qt was building ffmpeg_test ffmpeg_test-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_6__4_8_6__Release/release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ffmpeg was compiled with the [MinGW compiler](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/faq/) and sometimes libraries compiled with different compilers [may not always be compatible](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands). I was able to make my test program run correctly by getting the MinGW compiler and setting up Qt for MinGW. Also my version of ffmpeg did not require the changes involving stdint.h or inttypes.h. How this version of ffmpeg was able to compile using MSVC and cmake is still a mystery to me. For a path forward the question is if switching to the MinGW compiler is a option or if I need to compile ffmpeg for MSVC.